# MongoDB insert much data

Tags: mongodb

I would like to insert much data for index learning ( about 1000000 documents ). I was trying to insert it by `insert` or `insertMany` , but always only 3268 documents are inserted... Is any way for doing this in one query?

This code just print documents variable length

```
var documents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 300000; i++) { documents.push({ user: 'user' + i }); }
db.new.insertMany(documents)
```

and this adds only first 184 documents ( 2 hours ago it was adding about 2000 )

```
for (var i = 0; i < 300000; i++) { db.new.insertOne({ user: 'user' + i }); }
```

Maybe I am doing it bad?

Comment: How are you inserting records? Any language are you using? please be specific.

Comment: I try to do it in shell

Comment: Is there any code? Vague information is not going to help anyone .

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: I have updated my first post. I am using MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9

Comment: Shell is not right tool for this kind of operations. It's single threaded. Also create batch of 200 to 500 documents, not 300000.

Comment: I would like to "feel on my skin" how indexes speed queries ;) I restarted a computer and now it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try following snippet. It takes few seconds on my machine.

```
var documents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 300000; i++) { 
  documents.push({ user: 'user' + i });
  if(documents.length >= 300)
  {
    db.new.insertMany(documents);
    documents = [];
  }
}
```